# Replace values from specific columns in array with values in the adjacent columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I am trying to reduce the speed performance of the following problem. I have an array, for example:

```
list1 = [0.564,0.011,0.560,-1.100,0.344,0.912,-0.983]
list2 = [0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0]

list3 = [0.760,0.013,-0.580,1.120,0.144,-0.929,0.833]
list4 = [-1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

test_arr = np.column_stack((list1, list2,list3,list4))
```

That gives:

[image: first_array_example]

I will always have one column of varying floats (let us call these columns 'random_numbers') followed by another column that contains a mix of -1.0, 0.0 and 1.0 values only (let us call these columns 'ones_zeros').

The end goal is to replace any -1.0 or 1.0 (note: not 0.0) values with the value immediately to the left. For this example, the output would be:

[image: example_output]

Currently, I am converting the numpy array to pandas and applying the following function:

```
def replace_values(test_arr_df,random_numbers,ones_zeros):

    for cc in range(len(random_numbers)):

        test_arr_df[ones_zeros[cc]] = test_arr_df.apply(
            lambda row: row[random_numbers[cc]] if row[ones_zeros[cc]]==1 or row[ones_zeros[cc]]==-1
            else row[ones_zeros[cc]],axis=1

        )

    return test_arr_df
```

Applying it to our test case:

```
#Convert to dataframe
test_arr_df=pd.DataFrame(test_arr)

#Tell the function what is a variable column and what is a minmax column
variable_columns = [0,2]; minmax_columns = [1,3]

#Replace values
res_df = replace_values(test_arr_df,variable_columns,minmax_columns)
```

This pandas method works, giving the same result as the example output above. However, it is very slow. In other parts of my code I have successfully reduced the processing time by keeping numpy arrays and not switching to pandas, but I have been unsuccessful here.

So, my question is, is there a way to do this using numpy and not pandas? Or maybe a faster way using pandas? I cannot make headway on this, as I am constantly either indexing the wrong section or cannot replace the right rows/columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list1 = [0.564,0.011,0.560,-1.100,0.344,0.912,-0.983]
list2 = [0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0]

list3 = [0.760,0.013,-0.580,1.120,0.144,-0.929,0.833]
list4 = [-1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

df = pd.DataFrame({0:list1, 1:list2, 2:list3, 3:list4})

df.iloc[:, 1::2] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1::2].isin([1, -1]), df.iloc[:, ::2], 0)
print(df.to_numpy())
```

Prints:

```
[[ 0.564  0.     0.76   0.76 ]
 [ 0.011  0.011  0.013  0.013]
 [ 0.56   0.56  -0.58   0.   ]
 [-1.1    0.     1.12   1.12 ]
 [ 0.344  0.     0.144  0.   ]
 [ 0.912  0.    -0.929  0.   ]
 [-0.983 -0.983  0.833  0.833]]
```

---

EDIT: Version, where the column names are explicitly selected:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list1 = [0.564,0.011,0.560,-1.100,0.344,0.912,-0.983]
list2 = [0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0]

list3 = [0.760,0.013,-0.580,1.120,0.144,-0.929,0.833]
list4 = [-1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Pressure':list1, 'Pressure 0-1':list2, 'Temperature':list3, 'Temperature 0-1':list4})

df[['Pressure 0-1', 'Temperature 0-1']] = np.where(df[['Pressure 0-1', 'Temperature 0-1']].isin([1, -1]), df[ ['Pressure', 'Temperature'] ], 0)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Pressure  Pressure 0-1  Temperature  Temperature 0-1
0     0.564         0.000        0.760            0.760
1     0.011         0.011        0.013            0.013
2     0.560         0.560       -0.580            0.000
3    -1.100         0.000        1.120            1.120
4     0.344         0.000        0.144            0.000
5     0.912         0.000       -0.929            0.000
6    -0.983        -0.983        0.833            0.833
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Quick question, this works for the test array (as you've shown) but not on my 'real' array. I think this is because I have different column names (think pressure, temperature, etc.) rather than 0,1,2,3 labels. Is it possible to adjust this code to account for that? Using this code on it directly doesn't change anything at the minute. Edit: Looks like that should work, I need to figure out what the problem is quick and then I'll be back!

Comment: @SophieMayne See my edit. I added version, where you can explicitly name the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for x, y in np.argwhere(np.abs(test_arr) == 1.):
    test_arr[x, y] = test_arr[x, y-1]
```

Before:

```
[[ 0.564  0.     0.76  -1.   ]
 [ 0.011  1.     0.013  1.   ]
 [ 0.56   1.    -0.58   0.   ]
 [-1.1    0.     1.12   1.   ]
 [ 0.344  0.     0.144  0.   ]
 [ 0.912  0.    -0.929  0.   ]
 [-0.983 -1.     0.833  1.   ]]
```

After:

```
[[ 0.564  0.     0.76   0.76 ]
 [ 0.011  0.011  0.013  0.013]
 [ 0.56   0.56  -0.58   0.   ]
 [-1.1    0.     1.12   1.12 ]
 [ 0.344  0.     0.144  0.   ]
 [ 0.912  0.    -0.929  0.   ]
 [-0.983 -0.983  0.833  0.833]]
```

The logic: for all `x` and `y` coordinates of values `1` or `-1`, replace by left-hand side value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should have been clearer in my question - the columns with variable numbers can also contain -1,0,and1. Correct me if I am wrong, but this looks like it would replace those too? I had two good answers very quickly, I will try them both but for now the other answer worked well enough for me :)

Comment: It would only replace -1 and 1